# Pick a item from a list then display it

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a modal with a list of different sounds, the user has to select one of them, and then display it to the main page

modal page:

```
<ion-content text-center>

<ion-card>
  <div data-tap-disabled="true">
    <audio preload="auto" controls #audio>
      <source src="/assets/musics/sound1.mp3">
      </audio>
  </div>

</ion-card>

<ion-card>  
    <div data-tap-disabled="true">
      <audio preload="auto" controls #audio>
        <source src="/assets/musics/sound2.mp3">
        </audio>
    </div>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

How's the best way to do it?

EDIT1: Modal reponse:

```
modal.onDidDismiss().then((responseModal: OverlayEventDetail) =>{
      if(responseModal !== null){
        console.log(responseModal.data.music);
      }
    })
```

PS: Music is just the source of the actual music.

Comment: By creating a provaider that manage the link of the user's selection?

Answer (score 0):

You should create another page, and set onclick like `<div (click)="onClickSound(audio)" data-tap-disabled="true">`, and send sound in `NavParams`:

```
onClickSound(sound) {
    this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage, {
        sound
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm passing the source via parameter to the main page, but how I put the source as a variable?